# My MacBook is in boot loop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, bug

My MacBook Air is stuck in boot loop i.e. When I start my mac I see apple logo for some secs and the restarts again. This happens over and over. I can't get to os. When I try to get to utility disk using command+R, it doesn't get there either as it keeps restarting. Any idea how can I fix this?

Update

When I try verbose mode I get this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhOvfERZzRQ&feature=share

Update

Here are the screenshots. I'm not sure where it gets stuck but the first one is where it takes few extra seconds before it gets going further and the second screenshot is when trying to restart.
[image]

[image]

UPDATE

Based on @Ruskes answer, I created a bootable usb from another mac. And I boots infected mac from it but when it restarts the same restart loop began.

Comment: did you try Safe mode ?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't get there either. It stays on apple logo at the startup.

Comment: and the Internet recovery does not work either ? or the Verbose mode ?

Comment: Internet recovery when I try, I see list of wifi and I select one it waits for few moments and then restarts and again the loop of restarts begins. How can I get to verbose mode?

Comment: Command (⌘) – V key during start up

Comment: Yes you can see my updated question with a link to video. That's what I get on verbose mode.

Comment: Thanks, I can not read that, no need for video, just take a photo of the last screen so we can actually read it. The part when it gets stuck

Comment: Check the screenshots.

Comment: OK, this is going to take some time to read, meanwhile did you try to Log In as different user ? and disconnecting all peripherals. It is missing some files, so it might be bad disk.

Comment: No peripherals attached. I can't even get to login screen.

Comment: Do you have time machine back up or start up USB ?

Comment: Time machine yes but I can't even get to utility disk option using command R. So I can't use it. I m also ok to completely erase everything from hardrive.

Comment: You will need USB with OSX to perform further actions.

Comment: Ok let's do it. I have USB but not with OS X.

Comment: That would not help, you will need to download the OSX (Mojave or similar) then create a bootable USB, the process can take hours. Since your Hard Drive is probably damaged, you might want to consider going to Apple Service, they will give you FREE diagnosis and cost estimate to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Start with the basics: [PRAM reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and then check the drive/filesystem (below)

Boot your system while holding command-S.  Hopefully it will bring you to a command prompt.  You can then run these commands to check/repair the file system, and reboot

```
/sbin/fsck -fy
reboot
```

You may also want to run [hardware diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) on your mac.

Comment: Thank you the answer. It took me to command prompt and that command gives me this output. https://m.imgur.com/gallery/V6hpdHF

Comment: I tried to delete files in cache using this blog https://www.mklibrary.com/technology/macos-sierra-stuck-endless-rebooting-loop/ by going into terminal using above method but it says operation not permitted. Any why is that?

Comment: The imgur link doesn't work.  What is the error?

Comment: They are all read only file system. Thats what is says. `It can not be deleted, Read only file system`

Comment: This is via single user mode?  You'll have to mount the file system as read-write before attempting changes.  Single user mode will tell you what to do when it drops to the prompt: "/sbin/fsck -fy" then "/sbin/mount -uw /"

Comment: /sbin/fsck -fy gives me this output https://ibb.co/g6jHTG0

Comment: I am not sure if this is via single user mode. I simply started my mac using command+S. It started in command prompt as a root user. Then used your command above.

Comment: And when I do this  "/sbin/fsck -fy" then "/sbin/mount -uw /" this again my computer restarts and the loop of restarts begin.

Comment: OK so it seems that merely attempting to mount the disk causes a panic in single user mode which points to something severely wrong with the filesystem or the drive.  Did you try hardware diagnostics yet?  As per the other answer below, if you have access to another mac, you can make a bootable USB installer.  Or you can use internet restore which will let you wipe the drive and reinstall macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the typical boot up sequence.
Yours seems to be stuck at the "Secure Boot" point.
Recommend to completely wipe the disk and start over.

[image]

Comment: How can I completely wipe my disk as I cannot go to disk recovery etc modes..

Comment: use External (USB) with OSX on it

Comment: would this work https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201372

Comment: @null exactly you got it

Comment: Even this didn't work. I created a bootable USB from another mac. Tried to boot infected mac using bootable USB but when I choose to boot from usb it reboots and keeps restarting. Same loop.

Comment: Bad news, that would mean you have a hardware problem (the logic board) cost ca $600, but see Apple service for FREE diagnosis and estimate.

Comment: Did you try to run the Hardware test ? Hold cmd+D

Comment: CMD+D doesn't work either. When I press it it keeps restarting.

Comment: @null try the internet hardware test by holding option + D at boot.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way is the toughest: Forget the current disk inside the mac. Replace it with a new one. Boot from an external disk containing OSX and install OSX on the new inserted disk. Copy all files from Icloud or your backup back. Not the easiest way, but it should work. And as this needs replacing, i would visit the apple store.